# iphone - a reference to a cell

Tags: iphone

I am inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

At this point I have de indexPath and the tableView. How do I get a reference to the UICell object the indexPath represents?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```